# How to fix this 'Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError' error in angular 6?

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am using google map in my Angular 6 app.

I have been using this Google map in another project too. but recently I start another project and install angular agm. then used the API key that i used previous project. but it did not work. Said 'that it is an invalid key'. so i got new API key , but there is same problem.
this is the problem that shows in browser.

```
Google Maps JavaScript API warning: InvalidKey https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key util.js:222:33
Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error js:51:110
_.Jc
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js:51:110
on/this.l</<
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/8/common.js:73:375
_.qn</<
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/8/common.js:138:172
c
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/35/8/common.js:67:82
<anonymous>
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate:1:22
```

map.component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="mapDetails.latitude" [longitude]="mapDetails.longitude" (mapClick)=" onChooseLocation($event)">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="mapDetails.latitude" [longitude]="mapDetails.longitude"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

map.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MapDetails } from '../shared/models/map-details.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maps',
  templateUrl: './maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maps.component.css']
})
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {
  mapDetails: MapDetails = new MapDetails();

  @Output() public mapClickEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mapDetails.latitude=6.9271;
    this.mapDetails.longitude=79.8612;
  }
  onChooseLocation(event){
      this.mapDetails.latitude=event.coords.lat;
      this.mapDetails.longitude=event.coords.lng;
      this.mapClickEvent.emit(this.mapDetails);

  }
}
```

user-layout.module.ts

```
import { JobDoneComponent } from './../../job-done/job-done.component';
import { RatingComponent } from './../../rating/rating.component';
import { NotificationsComponent } from './../../notifications/notifications.component';
import { ProvidedJobsComponent } from './../../provided-jobs/provided-jobs.component';
import { CompletedJobsComponent } from './../../completed-jobs/completed-jobs.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserLayoutRoutes } from './user-layout.routing';


import { UserProfileComponent } from '../../user-profile/user-profile.component';

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import {ComplainComponent} from '../../complain/complain.component';
import { UserLogInComponent } from 'app/user-log-in/user-log-in.component';
//import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatDialog, MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material';
import { MatFormFieldModule,MatCardModule,MatStepperModule,MatSelectModule,MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatInputModule,MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatToolbarModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { PostJobsComponent } from '../../post-jobs/post-jobs.component';
import { PostPaymentsComponent } from '../../post-payments/post-payments.component';
import {MapsComponent} from '../../maps/maps.component';
import { DraftPostComponent } from '../../draft-post/draft-post.component';
import { JobRequestComponent } from '../../job-request/job-request.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(UserLayoutRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    ChartsModule,
    NgbModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey:'My_API_KEY'
    }),
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatButtonModule, 
    MatCheckboxModule, 
    MatInputModule, 
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatToolbarModule, 
    MatSidenavModule, 
    MatIconModule, 
    MatListModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    PostJobsComponent,
    PostPaymentsComponent,
    DraftPostComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    JobRequestComponent,
    ComplainComponent,
    MapsComponent,
    CompletedJobsComponent,
    ProvidedJobsComponent,
    NotificationsComponent,
    JobDoneComponent,
    RatingComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [RatingComponent]
})
export class UserLayoutModule { }
```

Comment: plz someone answer

Comment: Error message seems to be clear. API key that you applied in the AgmCoreModule.forRoot() is not valid. Double check your project in developer console and check if api key is correct.

Comment: no bought new API Key too. but still not working

Answer (score 3):

You might be loading Google Maps API twice, check if you are loading it in the provider

```
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {});
```

and also loading the script tag at the same time

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Try to remove the script tag and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not be the best approach in those environments where the key is already being used at multiple places. It worked for me as I was using it at just 2 of the places in my project.

Deleting the existing key and **regenerating a new key** worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidKeyMapError` happens when your API key can't be found.
So make sure you are using correct key that you generate or regenerate it.

The more details are [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages)